# using LUT & applyColorMap with opencv.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'd like to use `LUT` & `applyColorMap` in opencv.js. By default, they are not included, thus I tried doing a custom build, but I'm getting runtime errors when trying to use them:

`LUT`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) 6705216
```

That's pretty much all the information on the error there is.

`applyColorMap`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert "[object Object]" to int
```

It seems only the first overload of `applyColorMap` is supported, but I need the second one with a custom `userColor` matrix ([see docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gacb22288ddccc55f9bd9e6d492b409cae)).

###### Steps to reproduce

1. add `'LUT'` to `core` section in `./platforms/js/opencv_js.config.py`
2. add `'applyColorMap'` to `imgproc` section in `./platforms/js/opencv_js.config.py`
3. Build opencv.js with the following command:

```
$ emcmake python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_wasm --build_wasm
```

4. call the functions in javascript, e.g. like this:

```js
import cv_ from "./opencv.js"

(async () {
  const cv = await cv_

  // provide some `imgEl` here
  const img = cv.imread(imgEl)
  const lut = new cv.Mat.zeros(256, 4, cv.CV_8UC4)
  const out = new cv.Mat()
  // error is thrown here:
  cv.LUT(img, lut, out)
  // cv.applyColorMap(img, out, lut)
  lut.delete()
})()
```

###### System information

- OpenCV: 4.5.5
- OS: NixOS 22.05
- emscripten: 2.0.10

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? Trying to translate some python tutorials right now and not exactly sure how to set this up.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.